# Обозначение нестатического метода

Tags: java, документация

Как следует обозначать в документации нестатический метод класса? Если статический метод можно обозначить как *MainClass.main(String[] args)*, то как быть с нестатическим методом? *MainClass::nestaticMethod()* или как-то по-другому?

Речь идёт **не про Javadoc**, а про упоминание метода в тексте (при описании таска, например). Есть ли какие-либо общие правила для этого случая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java сигнатура метода состоит из названия и его параметров, соответственно невозможно сделать 2 метода статический и нестатический с одинаковыми именами и параметрами.

Соответственно бессмысленно пытаться подчеркивать:

- вот это `MyClass.getName()` статический метод
- а `MyClass.getName()`- нестатический.

Имя метода и его параметры однозначно идентифицируют метод и пояснения `public/private/static/protected` никак не нужны и только мешают восприятию.

В документации принято указывать `<class-name>.<method(param1, param2, ...)>`

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ!